# How to give a progressbar for the download?

Tags: android, asynchronous, progress-bar, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

In my application i'm downloading a video file. I want to show the progress bar for the download.

How is it possible through AsyncTask Concept?

Thanks,

Niki

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the onProgressUpdate method of AsyncTask.

If you know the size of the file you can set the max value in onPreExecute:

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
  ProgressDialog myDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
  myDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
  myDialog.setMax(maxValue);
  myDialog.show();
}
```

EDIT: added myDialog.show();

There are several methods to update the progress, either by incrementing by an amount or by setting the progress to a specific value:

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
  myDialog.incrementProgressBy(progress[0]);

  // or
  // myDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);

}
```

Then in the onDoInBackground():

```
@Override
protected void doInBackGround() {
  // your code
  publishProgress(1);
}
```

EDIT example with progressbar in layout:

In your layout file, add a progressbar like this

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
```

And in your asynctask:

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
  ProgressBar myProgress = findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
  myProgress.setMax(maxValue);
  myProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
  myProgress.setProgress(progress[0]);
}
```

Comment: @cantOna: Thanks a lot... But I cannot see the progressbar in my activity.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add myDialog.show() to onPreExecute. Was that the error?

Comment: @cantOna: Thanks a lot yaar... Can i customize the position of that progress bar and make is as a part of my application as it stay in my activites till it completes downloading.

Comment: Of course. The ProgressDialog is only one example. You can add a ProgressBar to your layout file, which you show in onPreExecute, and run updates to in onProgressUpdate as another example.

Comment: @cantOna:Can u pls explain?? I tried giving it my layout. Thing is that the progress is not seen.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to calculate downloading timi, and then implement progress bar as per time limit. here i enclosed the sample program of progress bar

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             while (mProgressStatus < 100) {
                 mProgressStatus = doWork();

                 // Update the progress bar
                 mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {
                         mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                     }
                 });
```

And this is the code for calculating the Time length for downloading file

```
//once the connection has been opened
```

`List values = urlConnection.getHeaderFields().get("content-Length")

if (values != null && !values.isEmpty()) {`

```
// getHeaderFields() returns a Map with key=(String) header 
// name, value = List of String values for that header field. 
// just use the first value here.
String sLength = (String) values.get(0);

if (sLength != null) {
   //parse the length into an integer...
   }
```

Comment: Hope when we use AsyncTask, there doesn't occurs the need of Thread.